# How to remove pending reviews directly in database

Tags: magento2, database, review, query

How can I remove all pending reviews in certain store view directly from database? What should I use as SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the status to not Approved

```
UPDATE `review` SET `status_id` = '3' WHERE (`status_id` = '2');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :-**

```
UPDATE `review` SET `status_id` = 2 WHERE `review_id` IN (SELECT `review_id` FROM `review_store` WHERE `store_id`=1)
```

**You can change your status_id and store_id based on your requirement.**